# Isnumber and two other requirements

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to return a 1 if two cells each contain a 10...unfortunately unless I resize my table it is returning a 10 for cells that only contain formula.

I can make it work (i.e. leave it blank when area1change doesn't contain a value, and return 1 if Star 2-score 1 contains 10) for this formula but can't seem to get it right if I want to add that one more cell also has to contain 10:

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER([@[area 1 change]])),IF([@[Star 2 - Score 1]]=10, 1,0),"")
```

Comment: You want 1 if both `[@[area 1 change]]` and `[@[Star 2 - Score 1]]` equal 10?

Answer (score 0):

```
=AND(ISNUMBER[@[AREA 1 CHANGE]],[@[STAR 2- SCORE 1]]=10,[SOME OTHER REFERENCE]=10)*1
```

Just use AND function and seperate each condition you want to check with a `,`.  When all conditions are TRUE, AND will return true.  If any condition is FALSE, AND will return FALSE.

In excel, when the boolean result of TRUE/FALSE is sent through a math operation such as --, -, +, /, *, TRUE is converted to 1 and FALSE is converted to 0.  Therefore perform a math operation on the the AND function that does not change its value and you will wind up with either 1 or 0.

Answer (score 0):

*Anna, Your Formula needs little correction and It should written like show below.*

`=IF(AND(Table1[@Qty1],Table1[@Qty2]=10),1,0)`

[image]

Actually `AND` checks multiple conditions and returns True if all condition evaluates True.

And When warped with `IF` then `IF` verifies whether conditions is met or not, if met then works with True option, and the Syntax of command is,

```
=IF(and(Condition1, Condition2), True option, False option).
```

**If you are stick with ISNUMBER then you Formula should written like show below.**

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(Table1[@Qty1]),Table1[@Qty1]=10),IF(AND(ISNUMBER(Table1[@Qty2]),Table1[@Qty2]=10),1,0),0)
```

**N.B.**

Check at last the Formula has `0`, which replaces `FALSE` with `Zero` for Row `2` and `5`, since both doesn't have `10` for either `Qty1` or `Qty2`.

*Adjust cell/Field reference as needed.*